# Unable to checkout when skipping recaptcha v2 popup

Tags: magento2, checkout, recaptcha

I am using **Magento 2.4.5-p1** and I have configured **Google ReCaptcha V2 invisible** for the **Checkout/Placing Order** section.

I am getting a strange issue while checkout.

**Summary of the Issue:** Place order button gets disabled when we click out side of ReCaptcha popup. We have to reload the page to get place order button enabled back.

**Steps to reproduce:** The steps to reproduce are given below:

- Add a product to cart and proceed to checkout.
- Try filling any false payment information in the checkout payment step, so that Magento starts showing ReCaptcha Challenge Popup when we click **Place Order** button.
- Once the popup starts showing, just click outside of the popup (instead of clicking on the images to solve captcha puzzle). It will close the ReCaptcha popup.
- Once the popup gets closed, try to click on Place Order button one more time. You will notice that the button gets disabled and we are not able to place order until we reload the page again.

Video link is added to show the process:

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/19184864?key=1e042d8bf5a6ac1aa0f5e5df4c98bd5a

**Update:** Seems like this is default bug of Magento, but I couldn't find any official/unofficial patch for it yet.